# RailsでいきなりNo such file or directoryが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsアプリで今までは正常に使えていたのに、急に "No such file or directory" と表示されて `rails g` や `rails t` などのコマンドが使えなくなりました。

Googleドライブのディレクトリはあるはずなので、エラーの原因がわからないです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    15: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    14: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/shiotaka/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    12: from /Users/shiotaka/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    11: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
     9: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     7: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     6: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
     5: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     4: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:30:in `call'
     3: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:33:in `rescue in call'
     2: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `cold_run'
     1: from /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76:in `boot_server'
/Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76:in `spawn': No such file or directory - /Users/shiotaka/Google (Errno::ENOENT)##
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイルパスにスペースが混じっていることが原因かなとエラーメッセージから推測されます。
メッセージが `/Users/shiotaka/Google`  で切れてるので。

> ```
> /Users/shiotaka/Google ドライブ/genba_rails/taskleaf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76:in `spawn':
> No such file or directory - /Users/shiotaka/Google (Errno::ENOENT)##
> ```

Googleドライブではなくて、別の場所でサーバを起動してみるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: +1: 関係しそうな issue を見つけました https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/516

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ファイルパスの空白を削除したところ、うまく起動することができました。